# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to edit the plan if it exists, otherwise I want to create it in PostgreSQL.

I have tried to solve the problem by searching similar problems, but have not found a solution.

The query works in the database but in the code it throws an error.

Here is the code that throws the error:

```
public boolean editPlan(Connection connection, EditPlanContainer planContainer){
        PreparedStatement statement;

        try{
            String editPlanQuery = "DO $$ " +
                    "BEGIN " +
                    "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public." + "\"" + planContainer.planName() + "\" " +
                    "WHERE \"LessonNumber\" = ? ) "+
                    "THEN " +
                    "UPDATE public." + "\"" + planContainer.planName() + "\" " +
                    "SET \"DayName\" = ?, \"Classroom\" = ?, \"Subject\" = ? "+
                    "WHERE \"LessonNumber\" = ?; "+
                    "ELSE "+
                    "INSERT INTO public." + planContainer.planName() + " " +
                    "(\"DayName\", \"LessonNumber\", \"Classroom\", \"Subject\") " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ? ,?);" +
                    "END IF; " +
                    "END $$";

            int subjectId = getSubjectId(connection,planContainer.subject());
            if(subjectId == -1){
                System.out.println("Error, no subject in DB");
                return false;
            }

            statement = connection.prepareStatement(editPlanQuery);
            statement.setInt(1, planContainer.lessonNumber());
            statement.setString(2, planContainer.dayName());
            statement.setInt(3, planContainer.classroom());
            statement.setInt(4, subjectId);

            statement.setInt(5, planContainer.lessonNumber());

            statement.setString(6, planContainer.dayName());
            statement.setInt(7, planContainer.lessonNumber());
            statement.setInt(8, planContainer.classroom());
            statement.setInt(9, subjectId);

            statement.execute();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error with edit: " + e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

line : int subjectId = getSubjectId(connection,planContainer.subject()); is working perfectly fine.
```